# Select pending requests (Friendship Restful Api) PHP and MySql

Tags: php, mysql

I want to develop a social networking application for Android where users could send requests for friendship and accepting the same. I have achieve that. Users can send requests to others like this:

Users table (users)

```
id                                               
name
email
...
```

Relationship table (relationship)

```
user_one_id - id of user who is sending the request 
user_two_id - id of user who is receiving request
status - 0 for pending request, 1 for accepting request and so on..
action_user_id - which user has done some action in table
```

But i'm not getting the exact number of pending requests when i use select query.

And now i will show you an example where user with ID 1 is sending requests and users with ID 2 and ID 4 are receiving request.

[image: Relationship table]

Now if i try to get pending requests using this query:

```
"SELECT u.name, r.user_one_id, r.user_two_id, r.status FROM users u, relationship r WHERE r.user_one_id = ? OR r.user_two_id = ? AND r.status = 0 AND u.id = r.user_one_id AND r.action_user_id != ?"
```

And parameters that are required are: `user_one_id`, `user_two_id` and `action_user_id`

In this example user with ID 1 is logged in and he shouldn't be able to see any pending requests because he didn't receive none, but if i send this query from above with parameters `1` for `user_one_id`, `1` for `user_two_id` and `1` for `action_user_id`, i'm getting JSON response like this:

```
 {
  "error": false,
  "requests": [
    {
      "name": "Dusan" // user with id 1
    },
    {
      "name": "Dusan"
    },
    {
      "name": "Jelena Radenkovic" // user with id 2
    },
    {
      "name": "Jelena Radenkovic"
    },
    {
      "name": "Stefan Dimitrijevic" // user with id 4
    },
    {
      "name": "Stefan Dimitrijevic"
    }
  ]
}
```

but this is perfectly works if user didn't send any request, like users with ID 2 and ID 4. If i send the same query with 2 for parameters, i'm getting then only one record as it should be. This is what i'm getting:

```
    {
  "error": false,
  "requests": [
    {
      "name": "Dusan" // getting only this user with id 1 because he sent request to the user with id 2
    }
  ]
}
```

This is okay until i send request to other users..
I hope that i have explained everything well and clearly. But if it's not clear, let me know, i will explained more or better. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can use `SELECT u.name, r.user_one_id, r.user_two_id, r.status FROM users u, relationship r WHERE r.user_two_id = ? AND r.status = 0 AND u.id = r.user_one_id` where `r.user_two_id = ?` is id of current user

Comment: without using action_user_id?

Comment: action_user_id indicates which user has done some action(send request, accept request and so on)

Comment: i dont think  `action_user_id` required in query as you mentioned in question about relationship `user_two_id` is the user who is receiving the request

Comment: so to count how many request is pending for logged in user, `user_two_id` is good enough

Comment: okay, but what if user with id 1 has also some pending requests ?

Comment: what you want to display? count of current logged in user? or all user? if id of current logged in user is 1 then user_two_id = 1 and loggedin user id is 2 then user_two_id = 2 and so on...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108497/discussion-between-dusan-dimitrijevic-and-chetan-ameta).

Comment: sqlfiddle your data,words problem are hard,data will help

Comment: @DusanDimitrijevic i sent some reference  link in chatroom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your schema `user_one_id` is sender id and `user_two_id` is receiver id, so to get exact pending request for current user(i.e. logged in user) your query will be as follow: (no need to use action_user_id in this case)

```
SELECT u.name, r.user_one_id, r.user_two_id, r.status FROM users u, relationship r WHERE r.user_two_id = <current_user_id> AND r.status = 0 AND u.id = r.user_one_id
```

or you can use join also in this case:

```
SELECT u.name, r.user_one_id, r.user_two_id, r.status FROM relationship r join users u on u.id = r.user_one_id WHERE r.user_two_id = <current_user_id> AND r.status = 0
```

Now if you want to get how many request sent by current user then change `user_one_id` to `user_two_id` as follow:

```
SELECT u.name, r.user_one_id, r.user_two_id, r.status FROM users u, relationship r WHERE r.user_one_id = <current_user_id> AND r.status = 0 AND u.id = r.user_two_id
```

and same changes in join also.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this:

```
SELECT s.user_one_id,us.name,us.email
FROM relationship as s
INNER JOIN user AS us ON s.user_one_id = s.id
WHERE s.user_two_id = "'.$current_user.'" AND s.status = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

try this query
SELECT COUNT(u.user_two_id) as friend_request_count from relationship r inner join users u on r.user_two_id = u.id where status = 0 and r.user_two_id = your_id